# When you click on a cell, the placeholderImage is transferred, after I go back down, go up and click on the same cell the photo is changing

Tags: ios, swift, image, imageview, uikit

I have a model

Where in ImageViewURL I get a photo and save it in ImageView, and the code for downloading

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class Modal:NSObject {

var name:String?
var date:String?
var ImageViewURL = ""
var ImageView:UIImage?
var stmp: Int?
var id: String?
var text:String?

}
```

When you click on a cell, the placeholderImage is transferred, after I go back down, go up and click on the same cell the photo is changing

```
Let u = URL (string: "link" + (modals [indexPath.row] .ImageViewURL))

cell.ImageView.sd_setImage (with: u, placeholderImage: UIImage (named: "loading"))

self.modals [indexPath.row] .ImageView = cell.ImageView.image!
```

The question is how to run the

```
self.modals method [indexPath.row] .ImageView = cell.ImageView.image! Before loading placeholderImage
```

all code

```
var modals = [Modal]()
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  modals.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if modals.count == 0 {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.date?.text = modals[indexPath.row].date
    cell.name?.text = modals[indexPath.row].name

   let u = URL(string: "http://www.---.com" + (modals[indexPath.row].ImageViewURL))
    cell.ImageView.sd_setImage(with: u, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "loading"))
    self.modals[indexPath.row].ImageView = cell.ImageView.image!


    return cell

}



 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

    let vc  = segue.destination as? ViewControllerDetail

    vc?.detail = modals[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
}
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wUVI.png) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdhPC.png)

Comment: What does your cell for index path method look like?

Comment: I added all the code

Comment: So is the issue on the table view? or when you pass the `Modal` object? Does the second view controller also have a table view?

Comment: The problem is that he sends a picture of the placeholderimage

Answer (score 1):

Is the cell image being updated in cell for row at index path?

Table views are designed to reuse cells. After the cell leaves the screen, it is reused as a cell entering the screen. The cell for row at index path method gets called every time a cell is needed. If you don't update the image in cell for row at index path, you may still see the "old" image.

Comment: Then you'll (probably) need to set the image view's `image` in cell for row at index path.

Comment: Image installed

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like this line:

```
  self.modals[indexPath.row].ImageView = cell.ImageView.image!
```

is probably the culprit.

If you pass the `Modal` instance and use its `ImageView` property to populate your detail view's image view, you may be getting the current image on the cell before it's been loaded from the web.

Comment: Without this code, `self.modals [indexPath.row] .ImageView = cell.ImageView.image!`
The application crashes when you click on a cell "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"